# How to access Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager or a QueueDescription instance in Azure Function version 2.0

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a azure function triggered by a service bus queue. I have access to the message, but I am also trying to access information about the queue using an instance of Microsoft.ServiceBus.QueueDescription; however, I am having difficulty using the Microsoft.ServiceBus namespace in the azure function. I initially received an error

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus: The type initializer for
'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Constants' threw an exception. Microsoft.ServiceBus: 
Could not load file or assembly 
'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. 
The system cannot find the file specified. System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load the specified file.
```

So I added all of the libraries for System.ServiceModel to the project; however, a similar issue arose in testing where a missing dependency could not be found.

Should I use a different way to get an instance of QueueDescription for the queue triggering the function pipeline? I have the following libraries in the project at the moment

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus (3.0.4)
WindowsAzure.ServiceBus (5.2.0)
```

Any ideas if either of the servicebus libraries included have the abilities to gain access to a QueueDescription instance?

Thanks

Comment: im not understanding what you need -- what does this mean? _I am trying to check the scheduled and active message counts in an azure function pipeline that begins with an azure function triggered by a serviceBusQueue_

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I edited the question. Basically it seems that at runtime, I do not have the necessary dependencies to use parts of Microsoft.ServiceBus; however, I thought it was a part of WindowsAzure.ServiceBus. In class libraries I have elsewhere that use the Microsoft.ServiceBus namespace and have WindowsAzure.ServiceBus package installed, I do not run into this error. It only happens in an azure function app

Comment: @pbordeaux - did you check out my solution? Or is it not relevant anymore to you?

Comment: @KaiWalter thanks! That was it, I had not been back on in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NamespaceManager is not supported anymore with the .NET Core compatible package `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` (which is a dependency of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` when using Service Bus within WebJobs or Functions), the package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent` and affiliates have to be used.

I did it in my Functions with Managed Identity but `AzureCredentialsFactory` also supports other forms of authentication:

```
...
    // some magic that determines subscriptionId, resourceGroupName & sbNamespaceName
...
    var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromMSI(new MSILoginInformation(MSIResourceType.VirtualMachine), AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
    var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

    var sbNamespace = azure.ServiceBusNamespaces.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, sbNamespaceName);
    var queues = sbNamespace.Queues.List();
...
```